# Is a Terminator line(twlight zone) wide enough for people to live in?

Tags: planets, space, environment, science-in-society

I'm writing a story about a planet tightly locked in rotation. Would it be viable for people to live within the twilight zone of the planet? I'm not talking about just a couple people I'm talking about cities of people, would there be enough space? Is any of this even possible?
Thanks so much!!!

Comment: There are so many questions about tidally locked planets that I wonder why there isn't a tag for it. Just do a search for "tidally locked" and you will find 50 pages of results. I'm sure everything that isn't super specific has been discussed here already

Answer (score 1):

Yes, no problem. Just arbitrarily declare that the habitable area is five hundred miles wide, or whatever size you need. No one knows enough about the meteorology of habitable rotation-locked planets to be able to contradict you, since we don't currently have any examples to study.

Comment: Saying "do whatever you like, it's your fictional world" doesn't really seem like a thorough answer.

Comment: @Giter Why waste precious time writing an answer that is 1000 lines long when you can say everything one needs to say in 3 sentences?